# Can't inline User fields to UserProfile admin tab - 'auth.User' has no ForeignKey to 'MyApp.UserProfile'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to add User fields into User Profile admin tab to be able to change every User attribute in one tab. The problem is that the `cmd` returns:

EDIT: Edited code according to Shang Wang's comment but still raises error:

```
<class 'MyApp.admin.UserProfileUserInline'>: (admin.E202) 'auth.User' has no ForeignKey to 'MyApp.UserProfile'.
```

In fact, I want to have either User inlined in UserProfile or UserProfile in User. The problem is that UserProfile has field `language` (note that this is not a Language model) which is `through-model` and I can't figure out how to inline it into the User (UserProfile can be inlined without problems), so I'm trying to inline User into UserProfile.

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
admin.site.register(AdminContact)

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'User_Profile'
    readonly_fields  = ('languages',)

class UserProfileLanguageLevelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfileLanguage

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

class UserProfileUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileLanguageLevelInline,User,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(LanguageTuple)
admin.site.register(Language)
admin.site.register(Job)
admin.site.register(UserProfileLanguage)
admin.site.register(Level)
admin.site.register(UserProfile,UserProfileAdmin)
```

Models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class AdminContact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class LanguageTuple(models.Model):
    language_from = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='language_from', null=True)
    language_to = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='language_to', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} to {}'.format(self.language_from, self.language_to)


class Level(models.Model):
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('unknown','Unknown'),
        ('standard','Standard level'),
        ('professional','Professional level'),
        ('native','Native speaker level'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)
    price_multiplier = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_name_display()


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    IBAN = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single', 'Single'),
        ('married', 'Married'),
        ('separated', 'Separated'),
        ('divorced', 'Divorced'),
        ('widowed', 'Widowed'),
    )
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
        ('coincidence', u'It was coincidence'),
        ('relative_or_friends', 'From my relatives or friends'),
    )
    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True,
                                                blank=True)

    # TRANSLATOR ATTRIBUTES

    is_translator = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # language_tuples = models.ManyToManyField(LanguageTuple,blank=True)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through='UserProfileLanguage')

    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    number_of_ratings = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

class UserProfileLanguage(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('userprofile', 'language'),)


class Job(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders')
    translator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='jobs',null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)

    # ZADAVA CUSTOMER
    description = models.TextField()
    file = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)
    language_tuple = models.ForeignKey(LanguageTuple,related_name='jobs')
    specialist = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def has_translator(self):
        return self.translator_id is not None


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.customer,self.language_tuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have `User` model in `inlines` for `UserProfileAdmin`, because `User` is a model not an inline admin. Edit it like this:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileLanguageLevelInline, UserProfileUserInline)
```

Comment: Thanks but now it raises Error: <class 'MyApp.admin.UserProfileUserInline'>: (admin.E202) 'au
th.User' has no ForeignKey to 'SolutionsForLanguagesApp.UserProfile'.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you created too many relationships depend on each other, like you have `UserInline` in `UserProfile`, and you have `UserProfileInline` in `User`, which I think it's not necessary. I think you should just keep `UserAdmin` and have `userpfile` as inline for that.